# Scooby Snacks in real life?

Tags: dogs, treats

I think I saw years ago some Scooby Snacks in real life: are they still made? I haven’t seen them in dog treats form in a while in stores. I also saw them as a fruit snack, just to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard of these as well, but actually never seen them in any of my local pet stores (in Poland, that is). But I've looked on [Amazon and it turns out that yes](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=scooby%20snacks), they're currently still in stock.

I'm not really sure whether they're the same brand you've seen years ago though. It could be the case that they're the same - "Scooby Snacks" besides being fictional, also turn out to be a licensed product (source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scooby_Snacks)).

And regarding your edit about them being fruit based: yes, from what I found it turns out that they also exist and are in stock. I don't want to come off as promoting a particular product though; instead, I will just post [search results of "Scooby Doo fruit snacks" from amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=scooby%20doo%20fruit%20snacks) and these on the top should be what you're looking for.